# Java EE install through ssh on a Linux AMI

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, installation, redhat, amazon-ami

I want to install Java EE 6 on a RedHat machine. The machine is actually an AWS AMI. I have installed JDK succesfully but when I try to install Java EE, the console tells me I hace to set the DISPLAY environment variable. I have googled for a while and found that Java EE can only be installed with an X server running(hence the DISPLAY variable). I have no idea how to install this as a linux AMI doesn't have a X Window environment (correct me and illustrate me if I'm wrong). How can I get through with this?

Thanks

P.D: I set the DISPLAY variable just to see what happens with no luck

```
...    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.openinstaller.core.EngineBootstrap.main(EngineBootstrap.java:208)
SEVERE INTERNAL ERROR: Can't connect to X11 window server using '10.98.135.210:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Comment: What are you really installing and what you really need, i.e. what do you understand by "installing Java EE"? If you want to install Java EE application server like Glassfish - you can download it in *.zip and just unzip it.

Comment: Well, I understand installing Java EE by downloading and installing the one of the files available here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html I want to use JBoss AS7

Comment: Please don't cross post questions across sites. Thanks.